# Passagem de parametro

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2015

Tenho o seguinte código que passa a data que esta no banco MySQL para a textblock:

```
 textBlock8.Text = (reader.GetString("Data"));
```

O que ocorre é que ele esta passando a data e a hora. gostaria de passar só a data.

Comment: Está obtendo um texto com a data, certo? A formato da data é garantido ser sempre igual? Qual seria ele?

Comment: Se você fizer `GetString("Data").ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")` não funciona?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a classe `Convert`, para converter para data

```
textBlock8.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(reader.GetString("Data")).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
```

ou utilizar o `DateTime` para dar um *Parse* na `string`

```
textBlock8.Text = DateTime.Parse(reader.GetString("Data")).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
```